# Ellipticals supported by random motions

Tags: galaxy, galactic-dynamics, stellar-dynamics

As opposed to spiral galaxies, which are rotationally supported, elliptical galaxies are said to be supported by random motions of their stars. I don't really have an intuitive understanding of this. How do random motions prevent a collapse?

Comment: The phrase rotationally supported is a poor one. There is no outward force in spirals or ellipticals, only an inward one that accelerates starsintheir orbits.

Comment: Nonetheless, both "rotationally supported" and "pressure supported" are used fairly often. (Though "pressure supported" is ambiguous, since sometimes it's used as in the OP and sometimes it refers to actual *gas pressure*, as in a rotating gas disk.)

Answer (score 3):

The same way rotation does.  If you look at each star, it is following some kind of orbit, so it has a motion.  The only difference between a spiral and an elliptical is that the motions in a spiral are all in the same plane and the same direction, but in the elliptical, they are all over the place.  So "random velocity" just means you look at a bunch of stars-- each one is still in an orbit, so it's no surprise it stays in orbit.